# What does "$$q" mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was studying Perl, and I came across the code piece below:

```
print $$q, "\n"
```

There is a `$q` variable that we don’t know exactly what it is. However, we know that when we run this code, it prints `"world"`.

So, what can `$q` be? What does `$$q` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `$q` is an *scalar reference*. So `$$q` gives you a scalar pointed by reference `$q`. Simple example:

```
$a = \"world"; #Put reference to scalar with string "world" into $a
print $$a."\n"; #Print scalar pointed by $a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$$q == ${$q}
```

`$q` represents a reference, and you are trying to dereference it in scalar context.

For more information, visit the [perlref documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).